# Replace new line | PHP

Tags: php, javascript, replace

I am developing a script which get all the content from a webpage using `file_get_contents()` then it removes all the HTML, JavaScript and CSS formatting and stores it in a variable.

Then I assign that PHP variable to JavaScript variable.
Now my problem is that the text (which I have assigned to JavaScript var) contains many newlines which gives me a JavaScript error on running my program.

Simple `str_replace("\n", "", $text);` didn't work for me. I have also tried `ltrim`, `trim`, `rtrim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a string to a JavaScript variable, you could use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var g_text = <?php echo json_encode($text); ?>;
</script>
```

**Note:** You can also pass arrays and numbers to JavaScript this way.

Comment: Hey guyz thansks all of you... specially Thai and Cary Chow

Answer (score 2):

You only need one call:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $string);
```

or

```
$string = strtr($string, "\r\n", '');
```

There's no need for multiple calls, or for having multiple combinations...  Yet it still takes care of the 3 possible line ending sequences (Windows `\r\n`, Linux `\n`, Mac `\r`)...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `str_replace("\r\n", "", $text);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It replaces all possible newline in all OS.

```
str_replace("\r\n", "", $text); // Replace CR+LF
str_replace("\r", "", $text);   // Replace CR
str_replace("\n", "", $text);   // Replace LF
```

Comment: IF you do the CR and LF replace then the CR+LF replace is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the stored string contains html, right?
If you want you can use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert the \n to the BR tag.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Please remember to always use double quotes when searching/replacing newline characters. If you use single quotes like:

```
print str_replace(array('\n', '\r\n', '\r'), '', $strBorked);
```

It will never work! You must use:

```
print str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n", "\r"), '', $strBorked);
```

This is because PHP does not interpret inside of single quotes, and \n is a character php only translates to a literal newline when inside of double quotes. This of course applies to all control characters.